# Entity Framework 6 multiple nested master-detail insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have this tables scenario

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTfDl.png)

So as you can see there are a multiple nested master-detail table and I have a requeriment where I have to insert at one time the first three entities, I'm using Entity Framework 6, Database First. (mvc Web api2). I managed to do first two entities at this way:

```
    Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1()
    {
       Field = "a field"
    };

    entity1.Entity2.Add(new Entity2() 
    {
       Field = "another field"

    });
```

//*******************************
//And the save is:

```
 using (var context = new backendEntities())
 {
    context.Entity1.Add(entity1);
    context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

And saves ok for the first two entities, but I'm not able or don't find a way for adding the next entity (Entity3). All the primary key are Identity autonumerics. How could I save these three entities at one time?. Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by `Entity3`, also are you using *Code-First* or *Model-First*?

Comment: What stops you from using `entity2.Entity3.Add( .. );` ?

Comment: @Luiso - Entity(1,2,3,4) are tables. I'm using Database First.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - How? I would have to create a new entity2 object but how manage the relation with the foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do the following?

```
Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1()
{
   Field = "a field"
};

var entity2 = new Entity2() 
{
   Field = "another field"
};

entity1.Entity2.Add(entity2);

var entity3 = new Entity3() 
{
   Field = "another field"
};

entity2.Entity3.Add(entity3);

var entity4 = new Entity4() 
{
   Field = "another field"
};

entity3.Entity4.Add(entity4);

using (var context = new backendEntities())
{
    context.Entity1.Add(entity1);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```